# DropdownMenuItem not full width in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, drop-down-menu, dropdown

[image]

I want to any way set Full Width 100% in dart/flutter. but it is not set in dropdown list in flutter.
my source code below in details.

```
Container(
  height: 50,
  width: 500.0,
  // width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
  child: Expanded(
    child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
      child: ButtonTheme(
        alignedDropdown: true,
        child: DropdownButton(
          isExpanded: true,
          value: _selectionRetailer,
          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1,
          // items: mRetailList.map((index) {
          items: mRouteWiseRetailList.map((index) {
            return DropdownMenuItem(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: new Text(
                index.retailerTitle + "_" + index.retailerAddress,
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10),
              ),
              value: index.retailerID,
            );
          }).toList(),

          onChanged: (sal) {
            setState(() {
              mRetailer = sal;
              _selectionRetailer = sal;
              retailerID = sal;
              print("SAVEDATADD" + "retailerID: $retailerID");
              if (reasonID == "0") {
              } else {
                startTime = Fhelper.CurrentDateTime();
                Fhelper.showToast(
                    "RetailerID: $retailerID, StartTime: $startTime, salesOfficerID: $salesOfficerID");
                print("SAVEDATADD" +
                    "RetailerID: $retailerID, StartTime: $startTime, salesOfficerID: $salesOfficerID,entryBy : $entryBy");
                clearAll();
              }
            });
          },
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```

how to achieve this full width in dropdown in flutter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `Expanded` and `Container` and follow the given below code

```
DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
        child: ButtonTheme(
          alignedDropdown: true,
          child: DropdownButton(
            isExpanded: true,
            value: dropdownvalue,
            icon: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_down),
            items:items.map((String items) {
              return DropdownMenuItem(
                  value: items,
                  child: Text(items)
              );
            }
            ).toList(),
            onChanged: (String newValue){
              setState(() {
                dropdownvalue = newValue;
              });
            },
          ),
        ),
      )
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the width property to MediaQuery.of(context).size.width